# Angular Google Maps search box template not displaying in phonegap (android)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, google-maps

Using http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/ for implementation of google maps using angular. Search box worked fine on mobile site. I then created a phonegap android build with the same code. Open the application and the search box was not being displayed. The search box is being called from a template that is run from the $templateCache in the .js file.

Here is the code (HTML)

```
    <form role="form" id="req-form" ng-submit="submitRequest()">
    <div id="search-box-container" class="form-group">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="searchbox2.tpl.html">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.map.location" class="form-control   autocomplete-search" placeholder="Enter Request Location...">
     </script>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-group panel-map request-ui">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" id="reqMapButton" style="opacity:0.3;" aria-expanded="{{ariaIsMapDisplayed}}" aria-controls="collapse-map" ng-click="toggleMap()">
    <h3 class="panel-title">
    <span class="open-map">
    Pinpoint Location on the Map<i class="collapse-arrow" ng-class="{'colarr-expanded': displayMap}"></i>
      </span>   
     </h3>
    </div>
   <div class="collapse-map" ng-class="{'expand-map': displayMap}">
<div class="panel-body">
<ui-gmap-google-map control="map.control" center="map.center"   zoom="map.zoom" events="map.events" options="map.options">
```

Here is the .js code

```
    .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
   uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        // key: 'AIzaSyCXetXbocz0evqoyhI__el2KmcTRdiuG18',
        v: '3.19',
        china: true
   });
 }])

 .run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put('searchbox2.tpl.html', '<input type="text" ng-model="$parent.map.location" class="form-control autocomplete-search" placeholder="Enter Request Location...">');
 }])
```

Code for $scope.searchbox

```
 $scope.min_request_date = shift_today_date_by_days(1);
        $scope.ariaIsMapDisplayed = 'false';
        $scope.displayMap = false;
        $scope.req = {expdate:new Date(shift_today_date_by_days(4))};
        $scope.searchbox = { 
            template:'searchbox2.tpl.html', 
            events:events, 
            parentdiv: 'search-box-container', 
            options: { autocomplete: true } 
        };
```

I'm new to angular so any assistance to display the search box would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If this helps I found an error in android studio logs displaying:
`09-15 21:48:57.870  21385-21385/com.example.vidpal I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(102)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined at g.createSearchBox (file:///android_asset/www/app/assets/js/angular-google-maps.min.js:7:24200)
            at g.createSearchBox (file:///android_asset/www/app/assets/js/angular-google-maps.min.js:7:21809)
            at g.init (file:///android_asset/www/app/assets/js/angular-google-maps.min.js:7:23204)`

Answer (score 0):

The search box appeared when change this src

`<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&v=3.19'></script>`

changed to

`<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&v=3.19'></script>`